# Can we create multiple today extension widgets for the same app in iOS8?

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

My question is quite simple, when developing a new iOS8 app, can we create two today extension widgets for the same app (each extension having a different functionality of app)?

I do not want to create a massive single today notification widget like how the Day One app have done it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you just add two or more widget/tooday targets to your workspace